# Plotting line.new() using ta.pivothigh() on different Timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

## Description:

I'm trying to create an indicator that shows the `ta.pivothigh()` and `ta.pivotlow()` values on different **timeframes** on the chart in the same position.
For now I'm at a good point, in the sense that the script itself is **working**. However I have a problem with the placement.

When i change my chart's timeframe, the script continues to calculate the values via the timeframe selected inside script, and so far so good. The problem arises with the positioning of the lines. For this reason I created a function as a workaround that can automatically position the lines at a number X offset.

The real problem is that this *work-around* has many limitations, it is often **not** precise most of the time.

For the moment I'm using the `plot()` function with `plot.style_steplinebr`, but I know well that I should use `line.new()`, the point is that I can't understand how to get the value of the **start bar** of the new pivot and the bar the value of **its end** or change.

## Code

```
//@version=5
indicator("Swing High/Low", overlay=true)
var float current_swing_high = na
var float current_swing_low  = na

string time_frame  = input.string('Daily', 'Timeframe',     options=['1 Hour','2 Hours','3 Hours','4 Hours','Daily','Weekly','Monthly'])
int    high_bars   = input.int   (6,       'High Bars')
int    low_bars    = input.int   (6,       'Low Bars')
float  high_source = input.source(high,    'High Source') 
float  low_source  = input.source(low,     'Low Source') 
int    offset_line = input.int   (0,       'Adjust Offset', tooltip="Use it to match the line with Highs and Lows")
bool   high_bool   = input.bool  (true,    'Swing High', inline='A')
bool   low_bool    = input.bool  (true,    'Swing  Low', inline='A')

def_timeframe(simple string _type) =>
    switch _type
        "1 Hour"  => "60"
        "2 Hours" => "120"
        "3 Hours" => "180"
        "4 Hours" => "240"
        "Daily"   => "D"
        "Weekly"  => "W"
        "Monthly" => "M"
        => "D"

def_adjustOffset(simple int num_bars, simple string _type) =>
    if _type == 'M' 
        if timeframe.period == "W"
            offset = (num_bars + 24)
        if timeframe.period == "D"
            offset = (num_bars + 140)
        if timeframe.period == "240"
            offset = (num_bars + 850)
    else if _type == 'W' 
        if timeframe.period == "D"
            offset = (num_bars + 28)
        else if timeframe.period == "240"
            offset = (num_bars + 190)
        else if timeframe.period == "180"
            offset = (num_bars + 260)
        else if timeframe.period == "120"
            offset = (num_bars + 385)
        else if timeframe.period == "60"
            offset = (num_bars + 770)
    else if _type == '240' 
        if timeframe.period == "60"
            offset = (num_bars + 20)
    else
        offset = (num_bars)
    
string time_frame_s = def_timeframe(time_frame) 
int    adj_offset_h = def_adjustOffset(high_bars, time_frame_s)
int    adj_offset_l = def_adjustOffset(low_bars,  time_frame_s)
float  swing_high   = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, time_frame_s, ta.pivothigh( high_source, high_bars, high_bars))
float  swing_low    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, time_frame_s, ta.pivotlow(  low_source,  low_bars,  low_bars))
bool   swing_high_b = bool(nz(swing_high) != 0 ? swing_high : current_swing_high)
bool   swing_low_b  = bool(nz(swing_low)  != 0 ? swing_low  : current_swing_low)

current_swing_high := nz(swing_high) != 0 ? swing_high : current_swing_high
current_swing_low  := nz(swing_low)  != 0 ? swing_low  : current_swing_low

plot(high_bool ? current_swing_high[1] : na, style=plot.style_steplinebr, linewidth=1, color=ta.change(swing_high_b) ? na : color.blue, offset=-(adj_offset_h + offset_line))
plot(low_bool  ? current_swing_low[1]  : na, style=plot.style_steplinebr, linewidth=1, color=ta.change(swing_low_b)  ? na : color.red,  offset=-(adj_offset_l + offset_line))
```

## Useful Images

[image: Position Issues]
[image: Work-Around Active with Offset]